How can I examine the validation applied to an email address in Livewire?
I have a Laravel app that I have upgraded from Laravel 10 to Laravel 11. It sits in an Alpine/Docker container. I was originally using the artisan serve system for the web server, but due to a bug in that component, I am finally upgrading to Apache. This process has thus caused me to upgrade from PHP 8.2 to 8.3 (I mildly wonder if I should have upgraded one thing at a time, but Docker challenges somewhat forced my hand).
It looks like the whole app is working other than one trivial thing. I am using a Livewire login system made by Laravel Breeze, and it is entirely stock. However, post-upgrades, the login won't work, and although there are no errors displayed, I can see in the Network tab response that the email address is failing validation. It did not do this before.
I thus tried using the email validator system, in a stand-alone fashion, like so:
<?php

use Egulias\EmailValidator\EmailValidator;
use Egulias\EmailValidator\Validation\RFCValidation;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$validator = new EmailValidator();
$ok = $validator->isValid("{redacted email address}", new RFCValidation());
echo $ok ? "OK" : "ERROR";
echo "\n";

In this code, the email address passes validation.
Here is a snippet of the login form:
class LoginForm extends Form
{
    #[Validate('required|string|email')]
    public string $email = '';

    #[Validate('required|string')]
    public string $password = '';

    #[Validate('boolean')]
    public bool $remember = false;

If I remove email from the validation annotation, it works.
Thus, how can I trace the Laravel version of this email check, to see what is going wrong? I don't know if the value is not getting passed to the validator, or it is doing an excessively strong check for which this address/domain fails.
Update
In the core of Laravel code, I am making some temporary changes to log what is going on under the hood. I have found that I can get the third-party email validation library to emit errors and warnings, and indeed there is an error:

iconv(): Wrong encoding, conversion from "WINDOWS-1252" to "UTF-8//IGNORE" is not allowed

The error comes from /project/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring/Mbstring.php. The page from which the call comes has <meta charset="utf-8"> in the HTML head, so I am not sure where the WINDOWS-1252 charset comes from. I wonder if my loaded extensions are different, and this has upset something.
I also notice my iconv configuration in phpinfo is rather blank. Perhaps this could be the cause?

Finally I also notice I don't have mbstring loaded, I will also try fixing that.

Try with: required|email

Thanks @PaulT, I have done a bit more digging, and got it to output the error. See my update; I wonder if my PHP extensions have changed.

The issue here is per my suspicion in the Update section. The Iconv installation was broken, likely due to my using Alpine rather than a Debian derivative.
While I expect I could have fixed the Iconv extension, I found that installing Mbstring was more straightforward. It looks like this one is tried in preference, and Iconv is only used if Mbstring is not available.
